# Importing Xcode developer profiles into login.keychain for the Jenkins user for building iOS apps

Tags: xcode, macos, jenkins

Folks,

I've done a fair amount of research on this topic, and still haven't found any answers so far.  I'm trying to achieve the same goals as demonstrated by @delaney05 in his post at [Jenkins on OS X: xcodebuild gives Code Sign error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245149/jenkins-on-os-x-xcodebuild-gives-code-sign-error) but I seem to be having some problems that he didn't (or, at least that he didn't mention).

Specifically, I can get the developer profiles exported via XCode (using the standard GUI methods), but the `security` tool doesn't seem to allow me to import those via the CLI to the `login.keychain` for the Jenkins user.  Of course, the Jenkins user is not a "real" user, and so you can't log in and do this using the GUI methods.

I tried posting an update to @edelaney05's article on this subject, but apparently the moderators want me to ask a separate question instead.

At this point, I'm seriously considering creating a real Jenkins user, then installing the app version of Jenkins as kindly provided by @sti a.k.a., [Sami Tikka](https://github.com/stisti).  At least this way I would be able to use all the Mac-standard GUI methods of exporting and importing developer profiles, `.mobileprovision` files, and other keys, certificates, etc....  Of course, doing that will make it more difficult to build out the cluster of Jenkins servers that we're going to need going forward, but I'm wondering if that really is the best solution right now.

Did I do anything stupid?  Did I miss anything?  Is there any additional documentation you'd like to see showing all the steps I've done through?  Thanks!

BTW, I did try to post a version that fully referenced all the pages with proper links, but as a "new user" I apparently don't have a high enough reputation score to post a question with more than two links.  ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try building your Xcode project via the command-line, and once this is working you can try setting the same environment in Jenkins.

Note that the user that Jenkins uses for running its commands is not related to the Jenkins-Login, but it is the **OS-X user** that had started the Jenkins **application**.
This user is probably 'daemon', which differs from the one you use for your regular work with Xcode.

(can confirm this by running "**id**" as the command in the Jenkins Job)

Good luck!