# error signing code of iOS App using Jenkins on MacOSX Lion

Tags: ios, jenkins, code-signing

When I try to build my iOS XCode project in Jenkins I get the following error:

> === CLEAN NATIVE TARGET MyTarget OF PROJECT MyProject WITH CONFIGURATION Debug === Check dependencies [BEROR]Code Sign error: The
>   identity 'iPhone Developer: My Name (xxxxxxxx)' doesn't match any
>   valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

After reading some articles (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245149/jenkins-on-os-x-xcodebuild-gives-code-sign-error?lq=1)) I've ensured that the login.keychain is present using:

```
MacMini:Keychains jenkins$ security list-keychains
    "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
MacMini:Keychains jenkins$
```

and that the *SessionCreate=true* is present in my */Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist*

PS. I would highlight the fact that the XCode running on my mac mini is successfully building the project,but if I run the command

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target MyTarget -configuration Debug clean build
```

...I still get the same error message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the xcodebuild command with a selected scheme.

Edit: Instead of

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target MyTarget -configuration Debug clean build
```

do this

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme MyAwesomeScheme clean build
```

Comment: In the original project I have 2 schemas 
"MyProject Develop",
"MyProject adHoc" and 2 Targets.
but when I run xcodebuild -scheme "MyProject Develop" it says there is no schema with that name

Comment: Use the one for the build you want to do. Which scheme is for Debug builds?

Comment: "MyProject Develop" but if I run it it says: "xcodebuild: error: The project 'MyProject' does not contain a scheme named 'MyProject Develop'."

Comment: Try to check the checkbox 'shared' at the scheme in manage schemes.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I had to check the "unlock keychain" option in the Jenkins job configuration (providing the password).

Comment: @dasdom :anyway now there is another problem which I reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295773/error-building-ios-app-on-jenkins-macosx-server