# Error building iOS app on Jenkins (MacOSX server)

Tags: build, jenkins, provisioning-profile

My Jenkins building job is failing with the following message

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET MyTarget OF PROJECT MyProject WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'MyCompany.MyProjet' could not be found
```

Now,if I try to run the xcodebuild command as jenkins user with a selected scheme:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target MyTarget -configuration Debug clean build
```

or this

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme MyAwesomeScheme clean build
```

I get the same error,BUT if I execute it as another user (my system main user) the build is successfully completed!!! It also works in Xcode.

This error start appearing after I fixed another code signing error copying my certificates in both Login and System keychain group.

**It looks like the *jenkins* user cannot access the provisioning profiles. Any idea how to fix it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create the directory `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` for the Jenkins user.

Next, copy the .mobileprovision files into that directory.

Last, set the provisioning profile in the Target build settings. 'Automatic Profile Selector' doesn't work with xcodebuild.

Comment: Saved my day! I was missing "for the Jenkins user." part!

Answer (score 1):

found a possible solution here http://code-dojo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html

Comment: There are security issues with putting the cert in the system keychain, since any user on that machine could sign an IPA file now. Still, it seems to be a common workaround and if untrusted people can get to the build server then you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

@Luke your answer helped me to move further.

I had to set up `Code Signing Identity` field with the whole profile (e.g. iPhoneDeveloper: NameSurname (XXXXXXXXX) )
+
set up full path to .mobileprovision file (/Users/username/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/test.mobileprovision) in `Embedded Profile` field

my current Jenkins version is 1.549