# MonoTouch + Jenkins - how to use my keychain accounts to build for iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, jenkins, keychain

I have successfully installed `Jenkins` CI. It uses it's own user `jenkins` for build operations.

I'd set up build steps. When Jenkins tried to build project for iOS devices, error appeared:

```
ERROR: No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain.
```

Seems like `jenkins` user account doesn't have keys and certificates in keychain, which my basic user account have. How to grant `jenkins` user access to my keychain entities?

*Note: seems like for `Xcode` native projects code signing problem was solved via [Xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin#XcodePlugin-Userinteractionisnotallowed).*

Comment: When I've done this in the past, I had to run Jenkins under my user account.

Comment: Yep. Now I'm think about it... Which tutorial did you use to run it under your account on Mac?

Comment: It was a long time ago, called Hudson then. It had a "launcher" that you could just set as a startup program when you login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your user's certificates to the system certificate. The Jenkins user will then be able to see those certificates. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477067/1131820