# Code Sign error when the job is built via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Referring to [Jenkins on OS X: xcodebuild gives Code Sign error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245149/jenkins-on-os-x-xcodebuild-gives-code-sign-error) and the steps mentioned in Problem 1, step 5:

5.security create-keychain .keychain

When I run this command, it asks for password. I entered my system password.
But it is not accepting. What should be the password here?

Basically, I have installed Jenkins and it has been installed as a separate user under /Users/Shared/Jenkins. Due to being this as a separate user, my code signing fails when I run the build job via Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The password is the keychain password, which is usually the same as the password for the user who created the keychain, which is the Jenkins user.  It may be possible to use a separate password for this, since you unlock it later in `security unlock-keychain` step, but I wouldn't bother.

Also, make sure you name the keychain, the line above indicates:

```
security create-keychain .keychain
```

you need something like:

```
security create-keychain signing.keychain
```